# Buffer streaming using buffer storage and persistent mapping is good and all but can we make it dynamic sized?

Tags: opengl

say I want an application that stream dynamic vertex data every single frame, and that data might vary in length.

e.g.
1st frame, say VBO(buffer storage under the hood) is using 3000 bytes of data

on the 2nd frame, application modified some data, and we want to update the VBO, what if now it's 5000 bytes of data and the buffer storage is full?

Buffer storage must specify a size upfront, do we dynamically re-allocate another larger buffer storage (imaging implementing the buffer storage like std::vector) and un-map the previous one?

or do we just specify a really large size in the very beginning when we created the buffer storage. but what will be the proper size?

Answer (score 2):

There really is no "simple" answer, since it's very problem specific.

But if you know the largest size your problem needs you can allocate that much.

Otherwise one strategy that could also be employed is a combination of both. If the size of the new data is larger than the old data, reallocate the buffer. So eventually you will end up with a buffer storage that fits your worst case.

Also you could have a look [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) for some pointers.